# Android Spinner OnItemSelect Loses Activity Data

Tags: android, spinner

Clicking a spinner item causes my activity.class to reload.  Which is working correctly.  However, the data that I passed to that activity, for example, logged in username is lost when spinner item is selected and activity.class reloads.  Should I implement SharedPreferences during onItemSelected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your needs. You can use `Bundle` to store your data and put it in your `Intent` object. This is more natural way to pass activity state.

In your case, such data as logged in username, should be stored in `SharedPreferences` because I think you don't want user to be logged out when your app is closed. Such data should be stored on a filesystem and `SharedPreferences` is a good choice.